# SQL: Select strings which have equal words

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Suppose I have a table of strings, like this:

```
VAL
-----------------
Content of values
Values identity
Triple combo
my combo
sub-zero combo
```

I want to find strings which have equal words. The result set should be like

```
VAL                MATCHING_VAL
------------------ ------------------
Content of values  Values identity
Triple combo       My combo
Triple combo       sub-zero combo
```

or at least something like this.
Can you help?

Comment: What RDBMS is this?  Your doing some pattern matching here which some RDBMS have built in functions wich could help.

Comment: @xQbert I'm using Oracle 11g.

Comment: Look at [UTL_Match](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_match.htm#ARPLS352) functions.  There's some decent matching functions there.

Comment: If the RDBMS you're using supports it, you can use a recursive CTE to split the strings by the space. Otherwise, you will need to create a UDF that accepts 2 strings and loops through a string to find any words in common. By the way, your result set is wrong, it should have either 4 or 8 results. But never 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One method is to use a hack for regular expressions:

```
select t1.val, t2.val
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on regexp_like(t1.val, replace(t2.val, ' ', '|');
```

You might want the case to be identical as well:

```
     on regexp_like(lower(t1.val), replace(lower(t2.val), ' ', '|');
```

Comment: I'm trying to run this query, but I'm getting error that t2 is an invalid identifier (in the replace part).

Comment: I think he means t1.val and t2.val `on regexp_like(t1.val, replace(t2.val, ' ', '|');`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of SUBSTRING and LIKE.

use charIndex(" ") to split the words up in the substring if thats what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Using some of the [oracle internal similiarity] found in UTL_Match (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_match.htm#ARPLS71219)  matching...

This logic is more for matching names or descriptions that are 'Similar' and where phonetic spellings or typo's may cause the records not to match.

By adjusting the .5 below you can see how the %'s get you closer and closer to perfect matches.

```
with cte as (
select 'Content of values' val from dual union all
select 'Values identity' val from dual union all
select 'triple combo' from dual union all
select 'my combo'from dual union all
select 'sub-zero combo'from dual)

select a.*, b.*, utl_match.edit_distance_similarity(a.val, b.val) c, UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER(a.val,b.val) JW 
from cte a
cross join cte b
where UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER(a.val,b.val) > .5
order by utl_match.edit_distance_similarity(a.val, b.val) desc
```

and screenshot of query/output.

Or we could use an inner join and > if we only want one way compairisons...

```
select a.*, b.*, utl_match.edit_distance_similarity(a.val, b.val) c, UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER(a.val,b.val) JW 
from cte a
inner join cte b
  on A.Val > B.Val
where utl_match.jaro_winkler(a.val,b.val) > .5
order by utl_match.edit_distance_similarity(a.val, b.val) desc
```

this returns the 3 desired records.

`But this does not explicitly check each any word matches.` which was your base requirement.  I just wanted you to be aware of alternatives.

[image]